# How to fetch the id of relational database in symfony 4?

Tags: doctrine

I have displayed the relational database data's in drop down that's working properly

But when i try to insert the data's to another form containing relational database tables as drop down It throws error

```
<select>
<option value=""> Select Category</option>
{%  for category in category %}
<option value="{{category.category}}"> {{category.category}}    </option>      
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

**While inserting the data's the error is**

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO new_product
>   (product_code, product_name, quantity, price, gst, hsn_code,
>   product_metric, product_dimension, supplier_name, category_id) VALUES
>   (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["RE45", "Shirt", 4,
>   456.9, 70.8, 2345, 3, 4, "sakthi", null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'category_id' cannot be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  these lines in **Entity**

```
public function __toString()
{
       return (string) $this->getCategory();
 }
```

**In twig**

TABLE HEADER

```
<th><h4>  category          </h4></th>
```

TABLE DATA

```
{%  for newproduct in newproduct %}
 <td> {{ newproduct.getCategory() }}</td>  //newproduct is another entity contains category entity as relatinal database 
{% endfor %}
```